# possible to default-disable XAML designer in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

A lot of my XAML pages were designed by hand and don't need to be shown in the designer when I open them-- I'd prefer just the XAML page.  The designer is getting in the way most times.

Is it possible to have the designer disabled by default, with the "resume loading the designer" link available in case I change my mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Tools
 ->Options
  ->Text Editor
   ->XAML
    ->Miscellaneous
     -> tick: Always open documents in full XAML view.
```

or you can just Double-Click the XAML tab.

Answer (score 2):

Right click and select "Open With..." and then choose the XML editor and select "Set As Default".

Now it will always open in the editor view by default, and you can still toggle the views if you need to.

Comment: This isn't as good as "Always open in full XAML view" because you loose what little Intelisense VS2008 has for XAML.

Comment: @Bryan, I've never actually noticed that. Thanks for the tip.