# Disable XAML UI designer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

How to disable XAML designer in VS 2011.

I have checked following links
[possible to default-disable XAML designer in VS 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511709/possible-to-default-disable-xaml-designer-in-vs-2008)

http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2008/04/24/quot-disable-quot-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2010/01/27/disable-visual-studio-xaml-designer-better-way.aspx

Problem with above is that intellisense also goes away with setting different text editor.

Comment: solution is very big and very slow. Any time i do some changes in XAML, solution hangs.

Comment: If it is that big and slow you might want to see if you can prevent any 'constructor' code running in design mode.

Comment: Thanks. i will check that, yes there are lots of code in the constructor (and lots of logic call, that i am looking to optimize). 
But still i would like to know the way if designer can be stopped with maintaining the designer.

Comment: Lots of code in the constructor is a bad thing for a designer. Logic belongs in the ViewModels. You could use System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode

Comment: I will also try this. This is new information for me.

Most of the logic is in viewmodels. Some logic is in code behind (due to certain restriction/features of METRO style apps).

Comment: In general I only add code to the constructors of the View that will load design time data. The loading of the ViewModels is only done at runtime

Comment: The last link you provide is the technique I use. It completely bypasses the XAML editor and intellisense still works for me.

Comment: very limited intellisense is working.
Only comments, CDATA, etc are coming. XAML intellisense is not working.

Comment: BTW, the reason to disable the designer is here:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2204137-improve-the-xaml-designer-performance

Answer (score 82):

In Visual Studio 2015 you can completely turn off the XAML designer in:

`Tools->Options->XAML Designer\Enable XAML Designer`

[image: XAML Designer toggle location in Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: The path is actually:
Tools > Options > XAML Designer > Enable XAML Designer
I also found that setting the "Default document view" to "Source View" was enough to stop my problems with the XAML designer.

Comment: It works for Visual Studio 2019 as well. Restart required.

Answer (score 26):

For Visual Studio **2012** the Link "user1007074" provided (http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/) tells:

> In the Tools –> Options menu, open the **Text Editor** node, then the XAML
> node, then select the **Miscellaneous** node; make sure that under the
> **Default View** heading there is a checkbox beside Always open documents
> in full XAML view.

also he suggest

> Right-click on any .xaml file in your solution explorer and select Open With…

Choose editor and click "Set as Default".  Many Thanks to David Alpert!

In Visual Studio **2015/2017/2019/2022**:

- In the Tools -> Options menu, open the XAML Designer node, then uncheck "Enable XAML Designer"

[image: VS 2017 Options Dialog to set Default document view to Source View or to disable XAML Designer]

As Mark Bell pointed out, it can be enough to set the Default document view to Source View, and leave XAML Designer enabled.

Comment: This is also disabling my F12 (got to defintion) functionality

Comment: @Iti Tyagi have you tried to set the Default document view to Source View, and leave XAML Designer enabled? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This applies for VS2012, maybe also other versions:

In VS Installation rename **XDesProc.exe** to **XDesProc.exe.bak**

For me it was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\XDesProc.exe

This way it has the best performance gain. The process won't start and VisualStudio will show an undisturbing exception window instead of the designer.