# Load xaml ResourceDictionary from dll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, resourcedictionary

I have made several `ResourceDictionaries` for our applications team to use with their future applications. I have deployed the contents of the class library project containing these dictionaries to a .dll file and would like to be able to use the dictionaries by adding a reference to the .dll file in a new WPF solution where I hope to make a new application.

The Class Library in my example is called "NWF_Class_Library.dll" and is saved in the same folder in windows explorer as the `MainWindow.xaml` file. Is it possible to retrieve the resource dictionaries from within it?

[image]

I have read articles about the best way for an organisation to [arrange their xaml](https://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/) resources, so it seems it must be possible, but all I find is ways to use the "//pack:application:..." syntax to reference xaml within the same solution as the wpf application. Here is a snippet of code, with the Source blank because nothing I have written has worked!

We had hoped that we could add the standard configurations as well as our more normal useful methods etc to a file that can be deployed with applications.

```
<Window x:Class="dll_ref_included.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source=""/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource myButton}">This</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It is posible with _"//pack:application:..."_ syntax. You may provide a strong assembly name and a resource name, that you wish to use. As far as I know, that this assembly must be loaded in your current AppDomain (added to reference of your project, or manually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/NWF_Class_Library;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
```

...where "NWF_Class_Library" is the name of the referenced assembly and "Dictionary1.xaml" is the name of the `ResourceDictionary` that is defined in this project.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) for more information about pack URIs and how to use them.

Comment: Unbelievable! I had already tried this syntax and get an error in the designer saying `An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/NWF_Class_Library;component/WPF Resources/Buttons.xaml".` but when I ignore the error and run it anyway (which I had not done before), I am presented with a perfect button! What the hell?!

Comment: The designer is a bit buggy and can't handle all scenarios. It's the runtime behaviour that counts. You may want to disable the designer altogether: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481645/disable-xaml-ui-designer

Comment: Man, so much time wasted for the sake of that! I am near the beginning of my xaml learning and was so sure I had the syntax right; just never actually pressed F5 when it was giving an error! I'll know to take the designer errors with more seasoning next time - I'll see if Blend does the same thing; it would be a pity not to be able to see the forms in the moment of designing them...

Comment: Microsoft Blend shows the preview properly - I'll use that. Man! So much wastage! Thanks.